# make function exception-safe

Tags: c++, wrapper, critical-section

In my multithreaded server I have `somefunction()`, which  needs to protect two independent of each other global data using `EnterCriticalSection`.

```
somefunction()
{
  EnterCriticalSection(&g_List); 
  ...
  EnterCriticalSection(&g_Variable); 
   ...
  LeaveCriticalSection(&g_Variable);
   ...  
  LeaveCriticalSection(&g_List);
}
```

Following the advice of better programmers  i'm going to use a RAII wrapper. For example:

```
class Locker
{
  public:
  Locker(CSType& cs): m_cs(cs)
  {
    EnterCriticalSection(&m_cs);
  }
  ~Locker()
  {
    LeaveCriticalSection(&m_cs);
  }
  private:
  CSType&  m_cs;
}
```

**My question:** Is it ok to transform `somefunction()` to this?
(putting 2 Locker in one function):

```
somefunction()
{
 // g_List,g_Variable previously initialized via InitializeCriticalSection

    Locker  lock(g_List);
    Locker  lock(g_Variable);
    ...
    ...
}
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current solution has potential [dead lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) case. If you have two (or more) `CSType`s which will be locked in different order this way, you will end up in dead lock. Best way would be to lock them both atomically. You can see an example of this in [boost thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread.html) library. [shared_lock](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.locks.shared_lock.constructor_defer) and [unique_lock](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.locks.unique_lock.constructor_defer) can be used in deferred mode so that first you prepare all raii objects for all mutex objects, and then lock them all atomically in one call to [lock](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.lock_functions.lock_multiple) function.

Comment: what if i always keep the same order of locking, does it matter?

Comment: Yes, but practice shows that it's really hard to do across any nontrivial application.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you keep lock order the same in your threads its OK. Do you really need to lock them both at the same time? Also with scoped lock you can add scopes to control when to unlock, something like this:

```
{
    // use inner scopes to control lock duration
    {
        Locker lockList (g_list);
        // do something
    } // unlocked at the end

    Locker lockVariable (g_variable);
        // do something
}
```

Comment: if i put these additional brackets, all trouble mentioned by Tomasz Kłak dissappear?

Comment: No, you need to keep the same order of locks in all threads, code I gave is just to show what scoped lock allows you to do.